# ansible win_ping is getting an error

Tags: redhat, windows-server-2012-r2, ansible

On the remote windows server

```
 PS C:\Users\name.domain> Winrm quickconfig
 WinRM service is already running on this machine.
 WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

On my linux host that has Ansible installed:

```
 # klist
 Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
 Default principal: user_name@domain.local

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/19/2016 10:02:18  09/19/2016 20:02:18  krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL@DOMAIN.LOCAL
    renew until 09/26/2016 10:02:12


/etc/ansible/hosts

 [local]
 127.0.0.1

 [windows]
 ip address 

[windows:vars]
ansible_user= name@Domain.com
ansible_password= password
ansible_port= 5985
ansible_connection= winrm



# ansible windows -m win_ping
 ip_address | UNREACHABLE! => {
 "changed": false,
"msg": "kerberos: requested auth method is kerberos, but requests_kerberos    is not installed, ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ip_address', port=5986): Max   retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by   ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3585d90>, 'Connection to ip_address timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))",
"unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: You may try asking at [DevOps site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops/visit).

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear:

> "msg": "kerberos: requested auth method is kerberos, but requests_kerberos is not installed

To make use of Ansible Windows support with Kerberos authentification some dependencies have to be installed on the control host:

> If you wish to connect to domain accounts published through Active Directory (as opposed to local accounts created on the remote host), you will need to install the “python-kerberos” module on the Ansible control host (and the MIT krb5 libraries it depends on). The Ansible control host also requires a properly configured computer account in Active Directory.

Consult the Ansible documentation for [active directory support](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#active-directory-support) for further instructions.

The case of the `ping` modules might be a bit confusing. These modules are used a ensure that Ansible is able to execute commands on the target host. One might think that Ansible would run `ping` command on the control box to the target host. But that is not the case.

So the actual `win_ping` module is written in `PowerShell`, will be executed on the target host and therefor needs a proper Kerberos setup. The code of `win_ping` module is in the [Ansible ansible-modules-core repository](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/windows/win_ping.ps1).

See also [Ansible documentation: How do Windows modules work](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#developers-supported-modules-and-how-it-works).